# How to use space-evenly in Flex-Layout

Tags: angular-flex-layout

How can I use [space-evenly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) in [Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation) in the fxLayoutAlign directive?  From this [sample](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs), I don't see that option.  I've tried reviewing the api documentation for fxLayoutAlign but there's [some problem with that](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/399).

```
<div fxLayout='row' fxLayoutAlign='space-evenly center'>
<div>Content 1</div>
<div>Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just apply style directly if there is not in the framework yet

```
        <div fxLayout="row" style="justify-content:space-evenly">
            <div>Content 1</div>
            <div>Content 2</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: With [a future update to flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/commit/bb58502c2af9fbf69308bf07a43357097b743808), `space-evenly` will be an option